# Daily save quota exceeded

Tags: android, google-api, androidpublisher

Could someone explain what is **Daily save quota**?

We use "androidpublisher_v3" from googleapis npm package ("googleapis": "^70.0.0") in our "task" for releasing new app versions.
To test this task on different platforms, we run a pipeline *several times a day*, which publishes the test application to different tracks.

Can we avoid the issue "Daily save quota exceeded" somehow?

Comment: Send fewer requests per day?

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your answer. We're wondering if there is a specific number of requests that we can send? As we know "The Google Play Developer API has a default limit of 200,000 queries per day". But according to the Google Cloud Console Quotas tab, we are not even close to that limit.
We also noticed that the number of publications for another test application before hitting the quota is more than for this one.

Comment: it depends on which daily quota you are hitting.  Try and get the full error message.